# How to activate and access GameObjects from inside a Prefab (with a button)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, prefab

I am currently trying to build a shop for my game. The shop is a list, that will be displayed onscreen and consists of Prefabs that each have a button component. On click, a hidden panel should be visible and different UI elements should be adjusted. I know that you can't directly reference GameObjects from a prefab, and I tried workarounds like a reference script from the actual scene and I am worried that using FindObjectsOfTypeAll() will be too slow, especially if I want to extend my game later on.

Below you can see my code:

```
public void LoadStore(PrisonerObject _prisObj)
    {
        //Here I am trying to get the references from a seperate script
        GameObject Panel1 = reference.ReturnShopPrisonerContainer();
        Panel1.SetActive(false);

        GameObject Panel2 = reference.ReturnPrisonerPreviewContainer();
        Panel2.SetActive(true);
    }

//This code is in a different Script
public GameObject ReturnShopPrisonerContainer()
    {
        ShopPrisonerContainer = GameObject.Find("ShopPrisonerContainer");
        return ShopPrisonerContainer;
    }

    public GameObject ReturnPrisonerPreviewContainer()
    {
        PrisonerPreviewContainer = GameObject.Find("PrisonerPreviewContainer");
        return PrisonerPreviewContainer;
    }
```

The ***LoadStore*** method will be called when the Button (on the prefab) is pressed.
I read a lot about this problem, but I can't seem to find a suitable solution for my problem here. I found someone saying there is a different approach to this problem, but unfortunately he didn't really explain his alternative approach. Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to activate game object after clicking on the game object created from prefab. If yes you can just set listener on prefab's button

```cs
// monobehavior on scene that creates objects from prefabs
class PrefabCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    private void InstantiatePrefab(GameObject prefab)
    {
        var obj = Instantiate(prefab, ...);
        obj.GetComponent<Button>().OnClick.AddListener(OnClick);
    }    

    private void OnClick()
    {
        // click handling
    }
}
```

Comment: what about if i had more Buttons on the prefab? how can i set the addListener to the second one?

Comment: The simplest answer is `prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()[1]`, but it is not the best practice, because if you change structure of your prefab you can get error in runtime. Better add component to the prefab, that will contain button you want to setup, so then you just do `prefab.GetComponent<'YourComponent'>().'ButtonProperty'.OnClick.AddListener`. Another simplification is to `Instantiate` your `component` instead of `GameObject`, this will also create a `GameObject`, but return instance of your component