# How to turn on a prefab with code in C# and unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, mrtk

I am new to C# and I am working on an AR project where I am showing directions to a section of books in a library. I have a basic scene set up where the user clicks on a button and something happens. I am using the Mixed Reality Tool Kit's directional indicator. I created 4 game objects that represent different subjects and are placed at different points in space in the scene. I have a directional indicator for each of those game objects and those directional indicators are prefabs. They are an arrow that points to that game object, so what I am trying to do is have them turned off and when the user clicks the button, it turns them on.

Comment: Prefabs are not something you "turn on" the are like moulds.   You can instantiate one though.

Comment: Use gameObject.SetActive(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Prefabs` are just files that contain `GameObject`, they aren't directly connected to the scene. If you want to create new `GameObject` from `Prefab` in runtime you can [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) it, and then keep reference to this **new** `GameObject`.

You also can check [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73715885/how-to-activate-and-access-gameobjects-from-inside-a-prefab-with-a-button/73716501#73716501), maybe it will help.

**Code example**

```cs
class SomeClass: MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject newGameObject;
    ...
    public void InstantiatePrefab(GameObject prefab)
    {
        newGameObject = Instantiate(prefab, ...);
    }    

    public void SetGameObjectState(bool state)
    {
        newGameObject.SetActive(state);
    }
}
```